# Strip Leading and Trailing Spaces From Java String

Tags: java, string, replace

Is there a convenience method to strip any leading or trailing spaces from a Java String?

Something like:

```
String myString = "  keep this  ";
String stripppedString = myString.strip();
System.out.println("no spaces:" + strippedString);
```

Result:

```
no spaces:keep this
```

`myString.replace(" ","")` would replace the space between keep and this.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but it means that the answers here were useful to people. I upvoted for that reason only.

Comment: Whilst this may be a duplicate, this is by far a better presented question. If anything, the other should be close as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: I switched the duplicates because this Q&A has far more views and favorites, and the other Q&A is actually a debugging question.

Comment: Made an answer with the [solution from JDK/11 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484070/1746118) - **`String.strip`** to this.

Answer (score 618, accepted):

You can try the trim() method.

```
String newString = oldString.trim();
```

Take a look at [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Comment: Works as a backward-compatible replacement for Java 11's String.strip().  I haven't had time to explore the subtle differences.

Answer (score 87):

Use [`String#trim()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method or `String allRemoved = myString.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "")` for trim both the end.

For left trim:

```
String leftRemoved = myString.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

For right trim:

```
String rightRemoved = myString.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of being able to tell how many leading/trailing spaces there are in the string.

Answer (score 34):

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29):

```
String.trim();
```

Answer (score 18):

trim() is your choice, but if you want to use `replace` method -- which might be more flexiable, you can try the following:

```
String stripppedString = myString.replaceAll("(^ )|( $)", "");
```

Comment: what all does it replace? Spaces and newlines maybe ?

Comment: I was searching for a solution to just remove trailing spaces but not leading spaces. I used: str.replaceAll("\\s*$", "") Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With Java-11 and above, you can make use of the [**`String.strip`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) API to return a string whose value is this string, with all leading and trailing whitespace removed. The javadoc for the same reads :

```
/**
 * Returns a string whose value is this string, with all leading
 * and trailing {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space}
 * removed.
 * <p>
 * If this {@code String} object represents an empty string,
 * or if all code points in this string are
 * {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space}, then an empty string
 * is returned.
 * <p>
 * Otherwise, returns a substring of this string beginning with the first
 * code point that is not a {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space}
 * up to and including the last code point that is not a
 * {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space}.
 * <p>
 * This method may be used to strip
 * {@link Character#isWhitespace(int) white space} from
 * the beginning and end of a string.
 *
 * @return  a string whose value is this string, with all leading
 *          and trailing white space removed
 *
 * @see Character#isWhitespace(int)
 *
 * @since 11
 */
public String strip()
```

The sample cases for these could be:--

```
System.out.println("  leading".strip()); // prints "leading"
System.out.println("trailing  ".strip()); // prints "trailing"
System.out.println("  keep this  ".strip()); // prints "keep this"
```

Comment: ***PS***: Migrating the answer here based on the comments from 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796121/how-to-trim-the-whitespace-from-a-string/50631235#comment89931502_50631235

Comment: Also see [*Difference between String trim() and strip() methods in Java 11*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51266582/2891664).

Answer (score 1):

To trim specific char, you can use:

```
String s = s.replaceAll("^(,|\\s)*|(,|\\s)*$", "")
```

Here will strip leading and trailing **space** and **comma**.

Answer (score 1):

s.strip() you can use from java 11 onwards.

s.trim() you can use.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void capitaliseEveryWordInASentence() {

    String mm = "Hello there, this is the cluster";

    String[] words = mm.split(" ");
    String outt = "";

    for (String w : words) {

        outt = outt + Character.toUpperCase(w.charAt(0)) + w.substring(1) + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(outt.trim());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Looks like you're answering a totally different question here.