# How to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the string in Java?

Tags: java, whitespace

I want to remove the leading and trailing whitespace from string:

```
String s = "          Hello World                    ";
```

I want the result to be like:

```
s == "Hello world";
```

Comment: I never thought about how to do such things without predefined methods. Assuming it's possible, then you need to iterate over all the characters in the string, but again you have to use charAt() method of class String. Is it predefined for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing whitespace from strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip Leading and Trailing Spaces From Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string)

Comment: If you're developing java, you should know two things: 1) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ 2) The verb you're looking is to TRIM a string

Comment: This is a 100% duplicate. I believe this kind of questions shouldn't be even asked on SO, this shows that an asker didn't even try to do the most basic research.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
 s.trim()
```

see [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Without any internal method, use regex like

```
 s.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\s+$", "")
```

or

```
  s.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "")
```

or just use pattern in pure form

```
    String s="          Hello World                    ";
    Pattern trimmer = Pattern.compile("^\\s+|\\s+$");
    Matcher m = trimmer.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(out, "");
    m.appendTail(out);
    System.out.println(out+"!");
```

Comment: What did the author of the question mean with "predefined" if this answer was accepted?...

Comment: @ka3ak I assumed "predefined method for removing leading-and-trailing spaces"

Comment: which is better? trim() or replaceAll using regex?

Comment: use `trim()` please.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s="Test "; 
s= s.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to use regular expressions for trivial problems. This would be a simple option:

```
public static String trim(final String s) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    while (sb.length() > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(0)))
        sb.deleteCharAt(0); // delete from the beginning
    while (sb.length() > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1)))
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); // delete from the end
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the String class trim method. It will remove all leading and trailing whitespace.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="          Hello World                    ";
s = s.trim();
```

For more information [See This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **trim()**. It only eliminate the start and end excess white spaces of a string.

String fav = "  I like apple  ";

> fav = fav.trim();
>
> System.out.println(fav);

Output:
I like apple //no extra space at start and end of the string

Answer (score 1):

String.trim() answers the question but was not an option for me.
As stated [here](https://closingbraces.net/2008/11/11/javastringtrim/) :

> it simply regards anything up to and including U+0020 (the usual space character) as whitespace, and anything above that as non-whitespace.
>
> This results in it trimming the U+0020 space character and all “control code” characters below U+0020 (including the U+0009 tab character), but not the control codes or Unicode space characters that are above that.

I am working with Japanese where we have full-width characters Ｌｉｋｅ　ｔｈｉｓ, the full-width space would not be trimmed by String.trim().

I therefore made a function which, like xehpuk's snippet, use Character.isWhitespace().
However, this version is not using a StringBuilder and instead of deleting characters, finds the 2 indexes it needs to take a trimmed substring out of the original String.

```
public static String trimWhitespace(final String stringToTrim) {
    int endIndex = stringToTrim.length();
    // Return the string if it's empty
    if (endIndex == 0) return stringToTrim;
    int firstIndex = -1;

    // Find first character which is not a whitespace, if any
    // (increment from beginning until either first non whitespace character or end of string)
    while (++firstIndex < endIndex && Character.isWhitespace(stringToTrim.charAt(firstIndex))) { }

    // If firstIndex did not reach end of string, Find last character which is not a whitespace,
    // (decrement from end until last non whitespace character)
    while (--endIndex > firstIndex && Character.isWhitespace(stringToTrim.charAt(endIndex))) { }

    // Return substring using indexes
    return stringToTrim.substring(firstIndex, endIndex + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.trim();
```

More info:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Why do you not want to use predefined methods? They are usually most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

See [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 11 String class has **strip()** method which is used to returns a string whose value is this string, with **all leading and trailing white space removed**. This is introduced to overcome the problem of trim method.

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()

Example:

```
String str = "  abc    ";
// public String strip()
str = str.strip(); // Returns abc
```

There are two more useful methods in Java 11+ String class:

1. [stripLeading()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading()) : Returns a string whose value is this string,
   with all leading white space removed.
2. [stripTrailing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()) : Returns a string whose value is this string,
   with all trailing white space removed.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple without `trim` method:

```
String s = "          Hello World                    ";
System.out.println(s.substring(10, 21));
```

Answer (score -1):

While @xehpuk's method is good if you want to avoid using regex, but it has O(n^2) time complexity. The following solution also avoids regex, but is O(n):

```
if(s.length() == 0)
    return "";
char left = s.charAt(0);
char right = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
int leftWhitespace = 0;
int rightWhitespace = 0;
boolean leftBeforeRight = leftWhitespace < s.length() - 1 - rightWhitespace;

while ((left == ' ' || right == ' ') && leftBeforeRight) {
    if(left == ' ') {
        leftWhitespace++;
        left = s.charAt(leftWhitespace);
    }
    if(right == ' ') {
        rightWhitespace++;
        right = s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - rightWhitespace);
    }

    leftBeforeRight = leftWhitespace < s.length() - 1 - rightWhitespace;
}

String result = s.substring(leftWhitespace, s.length() - rightWhitespace);
return result.equals(" ") ? "" : result;
```

This counts the number of trailing whitespaces in the beginning and end of the string, until either the "left" and "right" indices obtained from whitespace counts meet, or both indices have reached a non-whitespace character. Afterwards, we either return the substring obtained using the whitespace counts, or the empty string if the result is a whitespace (needed to account for all-whitespace strings with odd number of characters).

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight added explanation, hope it's useful / enough :).

Comment: Slight micro optimization, but wouldn't it be better to simply count until you find a non whitespace character rather than always counting to the middle?

Comment: @DavidBittner that's exactly what the code does actually? It doesn't always count to the middle, when both 'first' and 'last' are non-whitespace, the loop exits, which is what the first condition in the while indicates.

Comment: @DavidBittner updated the code and description to a more clear one, and fixed some issues that I had omitted, hope it's easier to understand now as well :)