# Replace SOME spaces - without Regex

Tags: java

I have the need to to remove the initial spaces from a string of variable length, that also contains other spaces. For example (it's using extracted .mp3 metadata), the initial String is

```
"         My Chemical Romance"
```

I'm unable to use a standard form of regex such as:

```
artist= artist.replace("");
```

As the output would become "MyChemicalRomance". Is there another way to remove the spaces at the start, especially as the String will be of variable length? 
Many thanks.

Comment: use artist.trim() to remove trailing whitespace (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108781/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-the-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the trim() function.

```
String.trim();
```

This will remove leading and trailing spaces.