# how do you use string.trim() method to trim the white spaces only at the end?

Tags: java, .net, string, c#-4.0

how do you use string.trim() method to trim the white spaces only at the end ?

I mean without affecting the spaces at the front side

ex : input : "   this is linkedin     "
o/p : "   this is linkedin"

Comment: Well, here, you wouldn't be using `String.trim()`.

Comment: Java or .net/C#? You need to make a choice...

Comment: In java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106757/removing-spaces-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 13):

Use regex:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

1. \s – any whitespace character
2. + – match one or more whitespace character
3. $ –  at the end of the string

You can read more from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is no right-trim method, but you can do it via several workarounds.
One consists of putting a non-blank character in the beginning of the String, trimming it and then removing the character. Using String.replaceAll() would allow you to do it with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you cannot do that with `trim()` .May be you can look for  Apache commons which  has an utility method [StringUtils#stripEnd()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripEnd%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29).

I haven't tested this , but hope it works for your purpose :

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

Another solution would be to iterate through the `char[]` obtained from the string in reverse and remove the unwanted characters !

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
    str = str.replaceAll("(.+?) +", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily have to use the **trim()** method,then this may be helpful:-

```
public class OP2 {
   public static void main(String[] s) {
      //object hash table 
       int index = 0;
       String s1 = "  sdfwf   ";
       for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
       {
           if(s1.charAt(i)==' ')
               index = index + 1;
           else 
               break;
       }
       System.out.println(s1.substring(0,index)+ s1.trim());

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, if the query was for .net language then you can use the built-in RTRIM method to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET/C# you can use the TrimEnd method on your string object:

`" this is linkedin ".TrimEnd();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegexRemoveEnd {   
    public static String removeTrailingSpaces(String text) {
        return text.replaceAll(" +$", "");
    }
}
```