# Jqgrid Column Expanding after updation

Tags: java, jqgrid, struts2

I am developing an site for college. In that i am displaying Staff Details in jqGrid along with **Employee Name,**  **Address,**  **Mobile Number** and 
**Departments**. The grid looks like the below [image: Before Updating] and the DB looks like below [image: Before Adding(DB)] when i alter any of the columns the **Address** column gets wider both in database and on grid.[image: After Adding] and DB looks like this [image: After Adding(DB)]
 Any reason why this is happening .

Comment: Before saving a varchar type to the db remove a whitespace. You could always do it in the trigger on before insert or update.

Comment: No @RomanC if i didn't update address filed still its taking whitespace

Comment: What do you mean by "...when i alter any of the columns the Address column gets wider.."?

Comment: In the sense when i update employee details only in address text area whitespace gets added at the start and end so the address column looks expanded

Answer (score 2):

If you still need the whitespaces for whatever reasons in the db you can always suppress them using `cssStyle="white-space: nowrap;` attribute on [`gridColumn`](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridColumnTag) tag.

Comment: No @ Roman C i don't want white spaces in my db. Can you suggest me the solution for that..

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string