# Android trimming unwanted trailing whitespaces using XML parser?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, whitespace, xmlpullparser, trim

I need to trim the extra white spaces while parsing the content from an XML in android? I'm using regular expression for this for removing the spaces between end tag and start tag
My code is:

```
topicValue.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><").trim();
```

But for getting the number bullets for the subtopics, the space is not removed correctly!!
Now its appearing like this.. Not in separate line and also white space before the numbers.
eg: 1. abcd 
    2. efgh  3.ijkl

Suggest any idea for this.. Thanks for help!!

Comment: Why is there a regular expression used with an XML parser? Don't do that. Correct the value/nodes *after* the parse.

Comment: @user2864740 because, i need to get the content from API

Comment: So, use the XML parser. This will allow access to either a DOM tree or sequence of nodes - whatever your poison is. *Do stuff with the parsed data,* not the text input to the XML parser.

Comment: is regular expression do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!!
Code is:

```
description.setText(str.replaceAll("(^ )|( $)", ""));
```

Reference link:
[Strip Leading and Trailing Spaces From Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string)

Thanks for help!!