# Need help on String Trimming Java

Tags: java, string, trim

I am getting this string from Db

```
str = "External - Internal ";
```

I want to remove the last whitespace from the string. I have already tried string.trim() and assigned it to another string
Kindly suggest as this is just not working. below is my code for reference.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
      String str = "External - Internal ";

      String temp = str.trim();
      System.out.println("1"+temp);
      temp=str.replaceAll(" ", "");
      System.out.println("2"+temp);
      temp=str.replace("\\r", "");
      System.out.println("3"+temp);
   }
```

Regards
Abhi

Comment: whats the issue with `trim()` it [worked](http://ideone.com/1ADa1p)  for me

Comment: Trim is not working, copy paste my code and can you try.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this simply through `string.replaceAll` or `string.replaceFirst` function.

```
string.replaceAll("\\s(?=\\S*$)", "");
```

If you exactly mean the space which was at the end then use the below regex.

```
string.replaceAll("\\s$", "");
```

Use `\\s+` instead of `\\s` if you want to deal with one or more spaces.

Comment: or `string.replaceFirst("\\s(?=\\S*$)", "");`

Comment: Thanks All for your promt response,

Comment: just want to confirm replaceAll("\\s(?=\\S*$)", "") if it removes only the whitespaces at the end. Please confirm

Comment: yep, it removes the last whitespace ie, in this input `foo bar bux`, this would also remove the space before `bux`. If you want to remove the space which was at the end, then use `\\s$`

Comment: tried both the options suggested by you, but space is not removed. kindly suggest

Comment: it works for me. Just assign the result to another variable and then print that variable.

Comment: Surprising how it is working with trim, as even I tried assigning it to another variable, I have found a way to handle it, but still looking for a neat way of doing this.

Comment: try `string.replaceAll(" (?=\\S*$)", "");`

Comment: I am using below code for now public static void main(String args[]){
       String str = "External - Internal ";
     System.out.println("+"+str.substring(str.length()-1));
      if(str.substring(str.length()-1).equals(" ")){
       str = str.replace(str.substring(str.length()-1), "");
        System.out.println(""+str);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here [Strip Leading and Trailing Spaces From Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string)

Look at the top two answers. Try right trim as myString.replaceAll("\s+$", "");

Comment: already tried it, not working in case of my string, I suspect it is normal space, so given a try for carriage return and tabs but that too not giving expected result :(