# How to find the given date is with in specified date range

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

Here is my code

```
boolean isWithinRange(String d)
{
    boolean withinDate = false;   
    try
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(d);
        withinDate = !(date.before(startDate) || date.after(endDate));
    }
    catch (ParseException parseException)
    {
     }
    return withinDate;
}
```

Inputs

2015-11-26
  2015-11-26 - Copy

Both returning true but what i required is "2015-11-26" should be true and "2015-11-26 - Copy" should be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) happily parses "2015-11-26" and ignores the " - Copy" part.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) states :

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
>   The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

To detect if the whole string has been used, instead use the [`parse(String source, ParsePosition pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) method. ParsePosition tells you where parsing stopped. Just compare this with the length of the original date string.

Comment: Do i need to trim the date string before parse?. Is there any other way without trim the date string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is we are passing the Date Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. This will verify the given input upto this format.

For example,

```
static boolean isWithinRange(String d)
{
    boolean withinDate = false;   
    try
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(d);
        withinDate = !(date.before(startDate) || date.after(endDate));
    }
    catch (ParseException parseException)
    {
        parseException.printStackTrace();
     }
    return withinDate;
}
```

The above code throw exception because we are passing Date format as 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'. So this will find the hour minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0):

just test if size is 10 before your test:

```
if (d.length!10) return false;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    isWithinRange("2015-12-11 - Copy");
    isWithinRange("2015-12-11");

}

public static boolean isWithinRange(String d) {
    boolean withinDate = false;
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dd = d.indexOf(" ") !=-1 ? d.substring(0, d.indexOf(" ")) : d; // Find valid String 
        if(d.equals(dd)){
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(d);
        withinDate = !(date.before(startDate)) || date.after(endDate)));
        }else{
            withinDate =false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException parseException) {
    }
    return withinDate;
}
```

Comment: That does work only if `d` has a space as the first character which is not part of the date. This would still return `true` for something like `2015-12-11-Copy`.

Comment: User need to take care about first space but he/she confuse about it , trim() the leading and lagging spaces of input string.

Comment: You will find  trim() [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string]