# Spring command object throws NumberFormatException for integer field if form fields contain space

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to write a common code or a configuration which can remove trailing or leading spaces from any strings which
are input from form submission in web application so that we should not get NumberFormatException at java code level while parsing 
those strings to Integer or number. For example " 15246 ". Because in case of spring command object if it has a integer field then it tries to convert it into integer implicitly. Except IE browser other browser do not let number field has leading or trailing space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip Leading and Trailing Spaces From Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string)

Answer (score 2):

Try with java inbuilt trim method

```
" 15246".trim()
```

Then cast into `Integer.valueOf(" 15246".trim())`

Comment: Actually I want a solution for all the input text. Using this approach we have to go field by field. it should be a common configuration which should handle this problem across the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring-Boot 2 it will just work out of the box:

Test.java

```
package hello;

public class Test {
    private Integer test;

    public Integer getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Integer test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{test=" + test + '}';
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
package hello;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testGet(@RequestParam("test") Integer integer) {
        return "" + integer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test_p", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testPost(@RequestBody Test test) {
        return "" + test;
    }
}
```

Test the POST with curl

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/test_p \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"test": " 876867"}'
```

> Test{test=876867}

Test the GET with curl

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:8080/test?test=%20542543' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
```

> 542543

The reason this works originates from the [class StringToNumberConverterFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToNumberConverterFactory.java#L62)

Which uses [NumberUtils which indeed trims all whitespace](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/NumberUtils.java#L201)

```
String trimmed = StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(text);
```