# Delete whitespaces in the beginning of each line and end the end of the each line

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this :

```
Mr Moh Jo\n
Address\n
 33333 City\n\n
Aland Islands
```

and I would like to delete whitespaces in the beginning of each line and end the end of the each line with following code but it didn't work

```
    public static String trimWhiteSpaceFromTheBeginingAndEndOFTheLine(
        String string) {
    Pattern trimmer = Pattern.compile("^\\s+|\\s+$");
    Matcher m = trimmer.matcher(string);
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(out, "");
    m.appendTail(out);

    return out.toString();
}
```

Expected result:

```
Mr Moh Jo\n
Address\n
33333 City\n\n
Aland Islands
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string

Comment: Possible Duplicate of a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796121/trim-whitespace-from-a-string :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use, it exactly does what u want

```
 String.trim()
```

You could do something like this :

```
String address = 
"Mr Moh Jo \n" + 
"Address \n" +
" 33333 City \n" +
"Aland Islands \n";

String [] addrLines = address.split("\n");
StringBuffer formatedAddress = new StringBuffer();

for(String line : addrLines)
{
    formatedAddress.append(line.trim()+ "\n");
}

System.out.println("formatedAddress: ");
System.out.println(formatedAddress.toString());
```

Comment: `String.trim()` doesn't trim whitespace from the beginning of lines in a multi-line String.

Comment: 1. `formatedAddress.append(line.trim()+ "\n")` Why are you nesting string concatenation and allocating new StringBuffer each line? This line compiles to `formatedAddress.append(new StringBuilder(line.trim()).append("\n").toString())`
2. StringBuffer is a synchronized (and far slower) version of StringBuilder. You shouldn't use stringbuffer unless you want to share the object across multiple threads.

Comment: @UMad well... I was going to use StringBuilder but then I thought I am not sure if this code needs to be sync... So I thought I better use StringBuffer.

And to address your first point, I dint know thats how it is interpreted.

Comment: That's how java does string concatenation.
You should just say:
`formattedAddress.append(line.trim()).append('\n');`. The code doesn't need to be synced if the stringbuilder is created inside the method and never leaves the method, since every thread calling the method works with a separate instance.

Comment: @UMad could you please point me to some links to know more about how the StringBuilder.append(line.trim()+ "\n"); works?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721998/how-java-do-the-string-concatenation-using` 
Read the answer with 18 upvotes (not the accepted one with 8 upvotes). If you have a `StringBuilder` already use the append method instead of using `+`.

Answer (score 5):

Just enable multiline flag in the regex.

`Pattern.compile("(?m)^[\\s&&[^\\n]]+|[\\s+&&[^\\n]]+$");`

Bam. Done.

You can also replace all that matcher code with `replaceAll` call:

```
public static String trimWhiteSpaceFromTheBeginingAndEndOFTheLine(
    String string) {
    return string.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\s&&[^\\n]]+|[\\s+&&[^\\n]]+$", "");
}
```

Comment: the code trimo the line break for example if have two line breaks between the city and Aland Islands the two empty line are trim which is not what I want only trim spaces not \n\n or \n

Comment: Hm, it works with one `\n`, but `\n\n` breaks it. Seems to be a bug with java regexes. Oh wait, \n are in \s too.

Comment: @Molwiko Fixed the expression

Comment: Some other regex magic is also going on at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4123385/873282

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 String s = "Your multi line string";
      System.out.println(s);

      String[] splitString = s.split("\n");
      s="";

      for(int i =0;i<splitString.length;i++)
      {
          splitString[i]  = splitString[i].trim();
          s+=splitString[i]+"\n";

      }
      System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: `trim()` has a rather strange notion of whitespace considering only c ≤ U+0020.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a single String. so `trim()` only omit the initial and end `whitespaces`, not in between. So split the string by `lineBreak`. and `trim()` all the seperate values.

```
       String[] inputArray = sample.split("\n");
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       for(String value : inputArray)
       {
           stringBuilder.append(value.trim());
           stringBuilder.append("\n");
       }
        System.out.println("Sample : "+stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: the string contain line break \n

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
private void doTrim(String str) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));
    String line;
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while( (line=reader.readLine())!=null ) {
        sb.append(line.trim());
        sb.append(NL);
    }
    System.out.println(">>" + str + "<<");
    str = sb.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(">>" + str + "<<");
}
```

Or hardcore version to loop string characters and update new buffer. This will trim trailing windows "\r\n" to unix "\n" newline. Little idxTail optimization newBuf could be avoided and only buf[] be used.

```
private String trimLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(String str) {
    char[] buf = str.toCharArray();
    char[] newBuf = new char[buf.length];
    int newCount=0;
    boolean isBegin=true;
    int trailingSpaces=0;
    for(int idx=0; idx<buf.length; idx++) {
        char ch = buf[idx];
        if (isBegin) {
            if (ch!=' ') {
                isBegin=false;
                newBuf[newCount]=ch;
                newCount++;
            }
        } else {
            if (ch==' ' || ch=='\r') {
                trailingSpaces++;
            } else if (ch=='\n') {
                if (trailingSpaces>0) newCount -= trailingSpaces;
                trailingSpaces=0;
                isBegin=true;
            } else if (trailingSpaces>0) {
                trailingSpaces=0;
            }
            newBuf[newCount]=ch;
            newCount++;
        }
    }
    return new String(newBuf, 0, newCount-trailingSpaces);
}
```