# how to check String start or end with space

Tags: java

Enter the player name. The name must be between 1 and 6 characters in length and not begin or end with a space character. If not meet the requirement reenter the name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player
{

    public void acceptName()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter playrname");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playerName = scanner.nextLine();
        while(playerName.length() < 1 || playerName.length() > 6)
        {
            System.out.println("Name length over 6,Please re-enter playername");
            playerName = scanner.nextLine();
        }            
    }        
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Trim leading or trailing characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691415/java-trim-leading-or-trailing-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

`String.trim()` will remove leading and trailing spaces, so comparing the length of the original string with the length of the trimmed one, should do the trick :

```
boolean hasLeadingOrTrailingSpaces = playerName.trim().length() != playerName.length();
```

Comment: It is not correct, cause name could be like "Xi yan"

Comment: @Dred : The question was about a string starting or ending with spaces, not containing spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can check it with `Character.isWhitespace()` function:

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(playerName.charAt(0)) 
  || Character.isWhitespace(playerName.charAt(playerName.length() - 1)) {
   //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
if(playerName.startsWith(" ")||playerName.endsWith(" ")){
        System.out.println("Incorrect name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find length of entered string
2. Perform `(String.trim()).length()`
3. Compare length ..