# how to trim specific characters off of Strings on Java

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to trim any single trailing `.` or `-`.  I tried doing this by doing something like `"f-o.o.".replaceFirst("^(\\.+)[-|.]$", "$0")`. The expected string is `f-o.o` but I'm getting `f-o.o.`.  Thank you.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691415/java-trim-leading-or-trailing-characters-from-a-string

Comment: It is `.replaceFirst("[.-]\\z", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression has two mistakes:

- you put a slash in front of a dot, making it match a literal dot, not just any character
- you put `|` into a character class, so your expression would remove not just `.` or `-` at the end of the string, but also `|`.

Use `"f-o.o.".replaceFirst("[-.]$", "")`