# how to cut all string "0" before other string number

Tags: java

I have data like this for price number from my broker:

```
String Price = "00000001970.00";
String Price1 = "0000000295.00";
```

This is the code I tried to use:

```
String Price2 = price.replace ("0", "");
```

But result was `Price2 = 197.` and my expectation is `Price2=1970`.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Trim leading or trailing characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691415/java-trim-leading-or-trailing-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

```java
String price = "00000001970.00";
// If you don't care about the decimals
System.out.println(price.split("\\.")[0].replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
// If you do care about the decimals:
System.out.println(price.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
```

See [How to remove leading zeros from alphanumeric text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800739/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Regex like this:

```
yourstring.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

guy. There was a sea of solutions to resolve your problem. For instance, you can look up like below:
` String price = "00000001970.00";

```
    Double dv = Double.valueOf(price);

    System.out.println(dv);

    int intValue = dv.intValue();

    System.out.println(intValue);
```

`
And you will get a result like below:

`
1970.0

1970`;

Besides, you can also look up like below:

`   String price = "00000001970.00";

```
 String substring = price.substring(0,price.indexOf("."));

 System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(substring));
```

`

Comment: Double and int are not proper data types to handle amounts. Both can lead to losing some part of an amount value

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not a big fan of regexes so I avoid them whenever possible.

Assuming that all your Strings are numeric, you could parse them to BigDecimal and then print that however you want. BigDecimal is prefer over Double if you care about precision.

To achieve what you want you could do something like so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String price = "00000001970.00";
    String price1 = "0000000295.0011";
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(price);
    BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(price1);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    System.out.println(df.format(num));
    System.out.println(df.format(num1));
}
```

Those numbers will be formatted as so:

```
1970
295.001
```

To learn more about possible formats read [DecimalFormat Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: recommend this for `price` number

Answer (score 0):

### [`Double#parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strPrice = "00000001970.00";
        double price = Double.parseDouble(strPrice);
        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way seems to use method `replaceFirst` from class `org.apache.commons.lang3.RegExUtils` (Apache Commons):

```
String price = RegExUtils.replaceFirst("00000001970.00", "0+(\\d)", "$1");
```

This will replace a substring of first zeros followed by any digit by this digit.