# Parsing CSV text file, ignoring commas with spaces around them

Tags: java, split

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{            
    line += ",N/A";
    String[] venue = line.split(",");
}
```

While reading from a CSV file, i'm using the split method to create an array of strings. I would like to implement the split function in such a way that it ignores all commas that have a space at either side of them. For example,

```
foo,bar, dev,war ,gen
```

should yield

```
String[] {"foo","bar, dev","war ,gen"}
```

I've tried looking for a decent explanation for string formatting in java but haven't been able to find anything resourceful enough to solve my problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796121/trim-whitespace-from-a-string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to remove spaces around commas, call [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) on the result tokens:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    tokens[i] = tokens[i].trim();
```