# Remove the white space

Tags: java

I’m using the .replace method to remove a character in a string. The issue I’m having is I’m using the parameters

```
.replace("#", "")
```

To remove the hashtag from a string that could be for example “# hello”
The replace method is doing what I want in removing the hashtag however it leaves an actual blank space in the string when I use it. So “# hello” becomes “ hello” when really I want it to be “hello”. Is there a different method I can use or a different parameter I can use to achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trim whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796121/trim-whitespace-from-a-string)

Comment: `.replace("#", "").trim()` would do it. The `trim()` method removes leading and trailing white spaces from a string.

Comment: @ThisClark .trim worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: @alwaysStuckJava until you have `"This # person"` ! `trim()` only "remove spaces" at the beginning and the end of the `String`.

Answer (score 5):

## Using regex

```
System.out.println("a # b c".replaceAll("#\\s*", ""));
```

This replaces # and optionaly some whitespace with nothing, so it outputs:

```
a b c
```

#### [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/fI7bwS/1) - Removes the highlighted sections

Comment: I would use a `replaceAll` and probably spaces before and after the `#` but the idea is there.

Comment: Changed to replaceAll, before and after would stop it replacing `#hashTag` though

Comment: @AxelH are you sure? https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hashtash - A moustache grown especially to hide drugs in.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException english is a wonderful language ... it was of course a typo ;) but I like the result !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
String string1 = "  #  WordIWantToKeep  ";//Blank spaces before and after
//Using the same variable
string1 = string1.replace("#", "").trim();
```

OUTPUT → `"WordIwantToKeep"`
`.trim()` removes all blanks at the beginning and end of the string

It's important the order of the `.replace()` and `.trim()`.
I recomend you to test this 2 different options, and see the output

```
string1 = string1.replace("#", "").trim();//Right answer for your post
```

OUTPUT → `"WordIwantToKeep"`

```
string1 = string1.trim().replace("#", "");
```

OUTPUT → `"  WordIwantToKeep"`

But the way sorry if my english level isn't good enough.